# Access List from statefulwidget to state

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pass a List from screen 1 to screen 2 statefulwidget and want to add data to it.

List type Question,

```
class Question {
  String questionText;
  String answerText;

  Question({this.questionText, this.answerText});
}
```

I passed the list to 2nd screen
class CardPage extends StatefulWidget {

```
  final List<Question> questionBank;
  CardPage({@required this.questionBank});

  @override
  ......
```

I added the content to the list from state,

```
TextField(onChanged: (text) {question = text;}),
TextField(onChanged: (text) {answer = text;}),
FlatButton(
     child: Text("Create"),
     onPressed: () {setState(() {
                         questionBank.add(Question(questionText: question, answerText: answer));});
                   }
)
```

Bt I don't know how to connect the List in stateful widget to the state to access it. I know there is widget for it but don't know how to completely import the list to state with it.
Anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function instead of list to your `CardPage`. It should be called when you create a new question. I think it is the most simple solution.

You CardPage should be like this:

```
class CardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(Question) createQuestion;

  CardPage({Key key, @required this.createQuestion}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CardPageState();
}

class _CardPageState extends State<CardPage> {
  String _question = '';
  String _answer = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      TextField(onChanged: (text) {
        _question = text;
      }),
      TextField(onChanged: (text) {
        _answer = text;
      }),
      FlatButton(
          child: Text("Create"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              final question =
                  Question(questionText: _question, answerText: _answer);
              widget.createQuestion(question);
            });
          })
    ]);
  }
}
```

Question lists owner state should be like this:

```
class _FirstWidgetState extends State<FirstWidget> {

  final List<Question> questionBank = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...
        CardPage(createQuestion: _createQuestion);
        ...
  }

  void _createQuestion(Question question) {
    setState(() {
      questionBank.add(question);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
simple demo.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<String> names = <String>['apple', 'samsung', 'shirsh'];

  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();

  void addItemToList(){
    setState(() {
      names.insert(0,nameController.text);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Example'),
        ),

        body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 5,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: nameController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Contact Name',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Add Item'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if(nameController.text.toString()!="")
                          addItemToList();
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),


              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      itemCount: names.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 50,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                          color: Colors.cyan,
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text('${names[index]}',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              )
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                  )
              )
            ]
        )
    );
  }
}
```